# Mod in VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having some problems with `Mod`.

My errors says Incompability

```
Sub test()    
For a = 1 To 5    
Dim cellValuekm As String    
cellValuekm = Range("C1").Offset(a, 0)    
If Mid(cellValuekm, 9, 1) Mod 2 = 0 Then
    Range("G1").Offset(a, 0) = "Kvinna"
Else
    Range("G1").Offset(a, 0) = "Man"
End If    
Next a    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mid returns a string, format the string to a int/long/double/float ect....

```
Mid(cellValuekm, 9, 1) Mod 2 = 0 



Sub test()


    For a = 1 To 5
        Dim cellValuekm As String
        cellValuekm = Range("C1").Offset(a, 0)
        If Len(cellValuekm) < 10 Then
            MsgBox "String is less then 10 digits"
        End If            
        If CInt(Mid(cellValuekm, 9, 1)) Mod 2 = 0 Then
            Range("G1").Offset(a, 0) = "Kvinna"
        Else
            Range("G1").Offset(a, 0) = "Man"
        End If
    Next a
End Sub
```

Comment: Like this?<Sub test()

For a = 1 To 5

Dim cellValuekm As String
Dim b As Integer

b = Mid(cellValuekm, 9, 1)

cellValuekm = Range("C1").Offset(a, 0)

If b Mod 2 = 0 Then
    Range("G1").Offset(a, 0) = "Kvinna"
 Else
    Range("G1").Offset(a, 0) = "Man"
End If


Next a

End Sub
Because that dident work either

Comment: or you could try `Cint(Mid(cellValuekm, 9, 1)) Mod 2 = 0`

Comment: thats because cellValuekm is a blank string I am guessing or not of the length you are expecting.  Right after you assign cellValuekm = Range("C1").Offset(a, 0) place a msgbox cellValuekm  and see what it returns.

Comment: Excuse me, I have kind of new at this. What do you mean by blank?

Comment: whats the value as it needs to be atleast 10 characters long since you are starting at position 9 and move 1 more position with mid

Comment: C2 is filled with 10 numbers and i want to see if number 9 / 2 is 0 or 1

Comment: Copy and paste the contents of cell C2 here

Comment: It dosent matter what the content is, it is 10 numbers nothing more. It could be 1111111111

Comment: I am not sure as the code does run as written and I have tested with 10 digit strings using numbers from 1111111111 to 9999999999. I can only reproduce the issue with a string less then 10 characters or not a number. --------No I do not get any errors.

Comment: Great!  I also added a check for 10 characters in the above.  if this resolved your issue please mark as answered.  Glad we got it going for You

Comment: Found the problem, it wasent the code. The problem was that there already was text inside the G column... Thanks for all help!

Comment: Okay, how do I marked it as answered and btw thanks for the Lenght check I think i will need that for another idea I had :)

Comment: @user1564291 You just click the tick next to the answer.